# Is there an R function for plotting normal probability plot for the effects in 2^k factorial design?

Tags: r

I am analyzing a 2^3 factorial design, and I want to specify the significant effects.

I used the fullnormal function but the significant effects does't appear ,and in the results two main factors are significant. Is there any other function that do the same work?

The factorial design can be replicated in the below example.

```
A <- rep(c(-1,1),8) 
B <- rep(c(-1,-1,1,1),4) 
C <- rep(c(rep(-1,4),rep(1,4)),2) 
y <- c(23,15,25,16,28,16,36,24,16,18,17,26,18,21,33,34) 
fit <- lm(y~ABC) fullnormal(fit$coefficients[-1])
```

Comment: Hi, please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: A <- rep(c(-1,1),8)  
B <- rep(c(-1,-1,1,1),4)  
C <- rep(c(rep(-1,4),rep(1,4)),2)  
y <- c(23,15,25,16,28,16,36,24,16,18,17,26,18,21,33,34)  
fit <- lm(y~A*B*C)
fullnormal(fit$coefficients[-1])

Comment: Hello Noora. Examples and such should be included in the original post. I have added your example to your original question, but please keep this in mind for future questions. This helps when people answer your question, and makes the example more readable.